# If $\dim V = n$ and $S$ is a linearly independent set in $V$, then $S$ is a basis for $V$, True or False?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm currently taking a linear algebra course, and the topic of the current section is dimensions of vector spaces. I came across the titled question in the practice problems. Online sources that I've seen say the answer is False, because we don't know the number of elements in $S$, therefore we cannot imply that $S$ is a basis for $V$.

I'm sure that I'm missing some key piece of information or I'm implying too much, but I thought it was True with Theorems 11 and 12 backing up my reasoning.

**Theorem 11**: Let $H$ be a subspace of a **finite-dimensional** vector space $V$. Any linearly independent set in $H$ can be expanded, if necessary, to a basis for $H$. Also, $H$ is **finite-dimensional** and $$\dim H \le \dim V$$

**Theorem 12 (Basis Theorem)**: Let $V$ be a **p-dimensional** vector space, where $p \ge 1$. Any linearly independent set of exactly $p$ elements in $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$. Any set of exactly $p$ elements that spans $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$.

My reasoning behind thinking the answer is True is as follows...

We don't know the number of elements in $S$, but we don't need that information to infer that $S$ is a basis for $V$, due to the aforementioned theorems. Since $S$ is known to be linearly independent, we know $S$ can have at most $n$ elements. By the **Basis Theorem**, $S$ is automatically a basis for $V$. Before you say it, yes I know the theorem states that $S$ must have **exactly** $n$ elements, but this is where I feel Theorem 11 comes into play.

If $S$ has less than $n$ elements, it is still linearly independent, so by Theorem 11 we know there exist elements that can be added to $S$ to expand $S$ into a basis for $V$.

I'm curious to know why what I have stated is incorrect, so if anyone can enlighten me I would appreciate it greatly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the piece that $dim S \le dim V$ includes the case where $dim S \lt dim V$. By Theorem 11, $S$ can be expanded to a basis for $V$, but this does not mean that $S$ is necessarily already a basis for $V$. Theorem 12 says that $S$ would be a basis for $V$ if $S$ contained exactly $dim V$ elements ($S$ is already linearly independent).

Comment: And that's about the gist of it. We can get into sticky set theoretic weeds here about why this is always possible, but it's not really necessary for the purposes at hand. More can be found at this posting:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458044/proof-of-basis-extension-theorem

Comment: I suppose my thought process was that you could apply Theorem 11 in order to get $S$ to exactly $n$ elements, thus fulfilling the Basis theorem's preconditions. But this makes sense. Thanks guys!