# Cannot understand Basis Theorem proof

Tags: linear-algebra

[Related Article](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1233059/422138)

I am really curious why the basis theorem works this way. It says $S$ spans $V$ so $S$ is a basis of $V$. And it also says if we think $S$ spans $V$, a subspace of $S$ called $S'$ can span $V$ but because it has to be $\dim S'=\dim V$, $S=S'=V$.

Then what does implementing $S'$ mean? The answer that $S$ spans $V$ is already made.

And why is $S'$ same to $S$?

And if $S'$ is same to $S$, the proof does not show that **all** sets which are linear independent, have $p$ vectors inside, and a part of $V$ are basis of $V$. Every basis are same is what it wants to say?

I am confused so much.. Please help!

Comment: I see no $S'$ in the related article ?!?

Comment: Fixed my question: I did not mean there is S' in the link. S' is in the theorem. Sorry for making you confused.

Comment: The theorem you talk about is in the linked article. Hence as there is no $S'$ in the linked article, there is also no $S'$ in the theorem.

Comment: http://math.ucdenver.edu/~esulliva/LinearAlgebra/SlideShows/04_05.pdf

Comment: Please look the proof of theorem 12 in 11th page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 12 makes two claims about the $p$-dimensional vector space $V$, $1\le p<\infty$ (though I cannot see why they keep unnecessarily giving $p=0$ special treatment):

- Any linearly independent set of exactly $p$
  elements in $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$.
- Any set of exactly $p$ elements that spans $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$.

To prove the first claim, we have to start from a linearly independent set $S$ of exactly $p$ vectors and then show that $S$ is a basis of $V$. You know from previous theorems that $S$ can be extended to basis, i.e., there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ with $S\subseteq B$. By definition of dimension, $|B|=p=|S|$. 
It follows that $S=B$, which means that $S$ was already a basis.

Similarly, to prove the second claim, we have to start from a generating set $S$ (not related to the set of the same name used in the previous paragraph) of exactly $p$ vectors and then show that $S$ is a basis of $V$.
You know from previous theorems that $S$ contains a basis, i.e., there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ with $B\subseteq S$ (well, the pdf calls it $S'$ instead of $B$, but I wanted to stick with the name I used in the other part - but again remember that we are in a different argument, i.e., this $B$ is not related to the $B$ used there). By definition of dimension, $|B|=p=|S|$. 
It follows that $S=B$, which means that $S$ was already a basis.

You may notice that the two proofs are completely "dual" to each other.

Now some critique of your question (which I hope helps you clear up some confusion):

- "a subspace of $S$ called $S′$ can span $V$" - nope, that should be *subset*
- "$\dim S′=\dim V$" - nope, $S'$ is a set and not a vector space, hence has no dimension
- "$S=S'=V$" - same here, $S, S'$ are sets and not all of $V$ (in particular, $0\in V$ cannot occur in any basis of $V$)

Comment: So thanks.. now I fully understand!